# Servers are still busy, how to delete them APACHE TOMCAT

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[error information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnHZb.png)

I tried deleting all running servers and tried cmd to get which ports are "listening" but it doesn't show up.When I run eclipse they give error that servers are busy, my 8080 and 8008 are in use

Answer (score 0):

First, find the process id of the service.

- Start a command prompt (cmd)
- `netstat -nao | find "8080"`
- Take a note of the process number - the rightmost from the command above

Kill that process

- Open the Task Manager
- Switch to Information
- Make sure the PID column is visible
- Find the process with the id found in the second bullet
- Kill it